# Ignore errors in database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, database-project

So, I have a database project in Visual Studio 2012.  I'm trying to do a schema comparison against a DB in another environment, but I'm getting compile errors in my one sproc that are preventing me from doing the comparison.  Not only do I wish to ignore all errors in the DB project, but even the errors it is throwing are not real errors and I cannot fix them.  The one it gives me is that my variable is not declared.  But it is, as a parameter for the sproc.  I know the sproc works.  I've used it many times in MSSMS.  Is there a way to tell the DB project to ignore errors and just do the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there must have been some sort of corruption in my database project.  I finally got fed up and recreated it by first completely removing the project from the solution and source control.  I no longer get these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily remove a project from the solution and effectively hide the errors by unloading the project (from the project context menu).  Then, when you are ready to reincorporate it, just reload the project, and it's like nothing ever happened.